# Consuming a WebService over SSL in Java

Tags: java, web-services

I want to consume a web service in Java and I am using JAX.WS. Everything is working fine until I try to consume a webservice over SSL (https). I have added the certificate of the site  to keystore using keytool. Still no success. Anyone has done it before ? The webservice is from a third party payment gateway like paypal-payflo etc... so regular webservice whose certificate comes from Verisign. Any tip would help. It is a SOAP webservice with wsdl.

The error trace:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to
>   access the WSDL at:
>   xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/creditcardWS/CreditCardService/v1?wsdl. It failed
>   with: Got Connection refused: connect while opening stream from
>   xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/creditcardWS/CreditCardService/v1?wsdl. at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLPars‌​er.java:173)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.ja‌​va:155)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.ja‌​va:120)
>   at 
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.jav‌​a:260)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:2‌​23)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:1‌​71)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java‌​:96)

Comment: Details would help us... what exception do you get? how do you manage your key stores, etc?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/creditcardWS/CreditCardService/v1?wsdl. It failed with: 
 Got Connection refused: connect while opening stream from https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/creditcardWS/CreditCardService/v1?wsdl.
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:173)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:155)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120)
 at  .....

Comment: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:260)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:223)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:171)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:96)

Comment: -------------- I am behind a firewall, but i tested it from home and still no success. I connect through the proxy by doing: System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.xxxxxxx.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

Comment: can you see the WSDL by going to the url in your browser?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I am able to read the wsdl with JAX.WS and generate the service reference classes and see the wsdl if I go online. I imported their certificate to my keystore in Java but I don't know how to make use of it to encrypt my transmission or change to an SSL Context .... any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does setting your own keystore to javax.net.ssl.trustStore help?

```
String keystorePath = "local.keystore";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystorePath);
```

Be sure to check if you can read from that path (current example assumes `local.keystore` is in classpath.

Comment: I have already done it, I think I should encrypt the request that's why and I don't know how to do it. I know the solution for posting a form with Apache HTTPComponents but I dont know how to encrypt in this type of request.

Comment: I think all those properties should be set at the communication level of those JAX.WS classes to work internally and not in the JVM level with System.setProperty()...